# Left Join with Partial match SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in SQL Server that I am trying to make a left join from so that all records from table1 are shown and any data from table2 is shown if it exists. They are as follows

Table1

```
id         Customername    Jobid    
--------------------------------
2754444    Jones           123    
2854233    Smith           234
```

Table2

```
key                Location    
-----------------------------
FD#2754444         London    
FEC#2854233        Liverpool
```

I can get an inner join query to work as below - but I obviously get only matching records, (which I dont want - I want all records from table1 and any matching values from table2)

This works:

```
$query = "select distinct table1.id, table1.customername, table1.jobid, table2.location, table2.[key]
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.id= RIGHT([table2].[key],7)"
```

So changing it to a left join:

This does not work:

```
$query = "select distinct table1.id, table1.customername, table1.jobid, table2.location, table2.[key]
from table1
left join table2
on table1.id = RIGHT([table2].[key],7)"
```

It does not return any of the table2 data. Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be very welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try it in SQL Server Management Studio or some other environment.  There appears to be nothing wrong with your query, perhaps something else is happening in your client/application.  *(As an aside, why do you need the `DISTINCT`?)*

Comment: Agree with @MatBailie that OP's code should work in MSSQL 2014.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a43a/1)

Comment: What's the data type of table1.id? It should work.

Comment: It sounds like you're getting rows back. Is it possible you're just seeing the mismatched rows first (the ones with nulls for table2?

Answer (score 0):

I put together a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7a43a/1) to show that your query should work (based on a guess about datatypes). Given that you've wrapped your queries as strings, that raises the question of whether your problem is actually with SQL, or if the ODBC (or whatever) connection is actually returning a parser error rather than a result set.  Have you looked at what the db is providing in return?  Have you ensured that there is whitespace between each word, even for line breaks (copying your text as-is shows CRs and LFs, but check your code); otherwise, it's quite possible that you're sending SQL Server something like "SELECT * FROMTABLEWHERETHING" rather than "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. For some reason the RIGHT was not returning anything so I managed to resolve with :

left JOIN [table2] ON [table1].id= substring([key],(CHARINDEX ('#',[key]  , 1)+1),7)

Thanks for all your responses.

Jim